# regex to split numbers and operators

Tags: c#, regex

How do I split below string to list of string with numbers and operators separated (string does not contain parenthesis or negative numbers).

Example:

```
inputString  =  1+2-2.3*4/12.12
outputList =   {1,+,2,-,2.3,*,4,/,12.12}
```

Below will give me numbers only. I need operators as well

```
var digits = Regex.Split(inputString  , @"\D+");
```

Comment: Why `2.3` parsed as `2.3`, but `12.12` - as `12, 12`?

Comment: I figured it was a typo.

Comment: I've removed space from input as that is not always the case. also corrected typo 12.12

Comment: Are there any parentheses, or negative numbers? Or do you only work with with this simplified type of input? See http://ideone.com/PhuOnK

Comment: no parenthesis or negative numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you confirm the structure of the input is rather simplistic - no parentheses, no negative numbers - you can just use a simple `\s*([-+/*])\s*` regex to split the string.

Note that [`Regex.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx) will also output all *captured substrings* in the result:

> If capturing parentheses are used in a [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d(v=vs.110).aspx) expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array.

So, use

```
Regex.Split(input, @"\s*([-+/*])\s*")
                    .Where(n => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n))
                   .ToList();
```

Just do not forget to remove empty elements from the resulting list/array.

**Pattern details**:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces (to "trim" the elements)
- `([-+/*])` - Group 1 capturing a `-`, `+`, `/` or `*`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces (to "trim" the elements)

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/PhuOnK):

```
var input = "1+2-2.3*4/12.12";
var results = Regex.Split(input, @"\s*([-+/*])\s*")
                .Where(n => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n))
                .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", results));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex.Matches instead of Regex.Split :

```
var test = "1 + 2 - 2.3 * 4 / 12.12";
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(test, @"\d+(,\d+)*(\.\d+(e\d+)?)|\d+|[\\+-\\*]"))
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me

```
/([\d\.]+)|([+-\/\*])+/g
```

FYI - LinqPad is an awesome tool to test Regex in C#